# Compound Couchbase 4.x Global Secondary Indexes

Tags: indexing, couchbase

When creating *compound* Global Secondary Indexes in Couchbase 4.x, I'm curious about the performance based on the ordering of the fields provided during the CREATE INDEX statement.

To illustrate, let me start with an example:

```
CREATE INDEX Index_1 
 ON `bucket`(field1, field2) 
 USING GSI;
```

Now when we execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `bucket`
 WHERE `bucket`.field1 = "value1"
 AND `bucket`.field2 = "value2";
```

It's very clear to me that using Index1 is obvious. However, there are a few cases I'm unclear about:

1. What if field2 is just provided and not field 1?

   > SELECT * FROM `bucket`  WHERE `bucket`.field2 = "value2";
2. What if field2 and field1 have reverse order in the WHERE clause?

   > SELECT * FROM `bucket`  WHERE `bucket`.field2 = "value2" AND `bucket`.field1 = "value1";

I know this example is only for 2 fields, but In my case I have something like 10 fields. In this case, creating many indexes to cover all the possibilities seems like a combinatorial explosion (factorial even, if you consider all possible orderings and ordering is important). It's even worse if missing fields is important because then you would need all possible orderings on possible subset of fields. That is, [(field1, field2), (field1), (field2, field1), (field2)], and this is only for 2 fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field order in the `CREATE INDEX` statement does matter. Your queries must include the leading field, `field1`, but can optionally include the trailing fields.  Your index has only one trailing field, `field2`.

Your first query will not use the index because it is missing the leading field. Be sure to drop your primary index when testing indexes or check the plan to make sure it does not include a `PrimaryScan`.

Reordering query predicates, as in your second example, does not change how the index is used. All leading fields are used in the `IndexScan`, regardless of where they appear in query predicates.

But, if you have an index with more than two fields, for example:

```
CREATE INDEX Index_2 
  ON `bucket`(field1, field2, field3, field4) 
  USING GSI;
```

And your query excludes the second field:

```
SELECT * FROM `bucket`
  WHERE `bucket`.field1 = "value1" 
    // field2 not specified
    AND `bucket`.field3 = "value3";
```

Only one leading field is specified, so the index is only scanned using the `field1` predicate.  The query service must do the remaining work to filter items with the `field3` value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeff. Helped solidify my understanding.